# Install Ubuntu Touch Emulator in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, ubuntu-touch

I want to install Ubuntu-touch emulator on my Ubuntu 12.04 64bit Desktop edition.
How could i do that?

Answer (score 1):

Add the PPA and install the emulator using the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:phablet-team/tools
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-emulator
```

Note that:

When you create a new instance  you may get the following error:

```
Error while converting ~/.local/share/ubuntu-emulator/UbuntuTouch/system.img: Unknown option 'compat' qemu-img: Invalid options for file format 'qcow2'.`
```

Just ignore it everything will work.

Comment: Got the same error but I am unable to see the emulator in the list. What should I do?